# Python Dynamically Generate HTML Page on GAE

Tags: python, html, google-app-engine, rest

On GAE, I need to make some REST calls to a PiCloud server, then create an output page based on PiCloud return values. However, it will take several minutes for PiCloud to process the model. Thus I am wondering if I could create a 'loading' page first, and after finishing calculation, present the real output page.

In detail, the questions is how do I keep checking the status of my REST service and then generate different HTML pages based upon.

I appreciate any suggestions and comments!

#### PS: jQuery BlockUI seems to be good example, but it requires to estimate the timeout duration, which I could not guess...

Function to Call REST Service:

```
def get_jid(pdf_t, pdf_nop, pdf_p):
    response = urlfetch.fetch(url=url, payload=data, method=urlfetch.POST, headers=http_headers) 
    jid= json.loads(response.content)['jid']
    output_st = "running"
        
    while output_st!="done":
        response_st = urlfetch.fetch(url='https://api.picloud.com/job/?jids=%s&field=status' %jid, headers=http_headers)
        output_st = json.loads(response_st.content)['info']['%s' %jid]['status']

    url_val = 'https://api.picloud.com/job/result/?jid='+str(jid)
    response_val = urlfetch.fetch(url=url_val, method=urlfetch.GET, headers=http_headers)
    output_val = json.loads(response_val.content)['result']
    return(jid, output_st, output_val)
```

Generate HTML Page:

```
class pdfPage_loading(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):                              
        final_res=get_jid(pdf_t, pdf_nop, pdf_p)[2]
        html = html + template.render(templatepath + 'popup_pdf_eco.html', {
            'title':'Ubertool',
            'model_page':'',
            'model_attributes':'Please wait','text_paragraph':''})
        self.response.out.write(html)


class pdfPage_done(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):                              
        final_res=get_jid(pdf_t, pdf_nop, pdf_p)[2]
        html = html + template.render(templatepath + 'popup_pdf_eco.html', {
            'title':'Ubertool',
            'model_page':final_res,
            'model_attributes':'Please download your PDF here','text_paragraph':''})
        self.response.out.write(html)

app_loading = webapp.WSGIApplication([('/.*', pdfPage_loading)], debug=True)
app_done = webapp.WSGIApplication([('/.*', pdfPage_done)], debug=True)

def main():
    ##Here is the problematic part:
    if get_jid(pdf_t, pdf_nop, pdf_p)!='done':
        run_wsgi_app(app_pre)
    else:
        run_wsgi_app(app)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, you do not need multiple WSGIApplication handlers. You can base requests off of URLs and GET/POST params.

I would use a mixture of tasks and the Channel API:

When a user visits the page:

1. Create a channel token for the user to use
2. Make the REST API calls
3. Kick off a task (described below) passing it the created token and the id of the PiCloud job
4. Show the "loading page" and have the user connect to the Channel API with the token created in step 1

In the task, have it check on the status of the PiCloud job. If the status is not done, have the task setup a new task to call itself again, and check on the status of the job. Once the job is complete, pass the data along through the Channel API to the user so that they can then load the contents of the page or redirect to a page that will have the contents ready for them.

Example status check code (this is using the example code from PiCloud, you can use your own requests as you have been to get the status through `urlfetch` - this is merely meant as an example so you can plug your code in to work as needed):

```
import cloud
from google.appengine.api import taskqueue
from google.appengine.api import channel

#<Your other hanlders here>

class CheckStatus(webapp.RequestHandler):
  def post(self):
    job_id = self.request.get('job_id')
    token = self.request.get('token')
    status = cloud.get('status')
    if status != 'done':
       taskqueue.add(url='/checkstatus', params={'job_id': job_id, 'token': token}, method="POST", countdown=3)
       return
    channel.send_message(token, '<some message here>')

app = webapp.WSGIApplication([('/done', pdfPage_done),
                              ('/checkstatus', CheckStatus),
                              ('/.*', pdfPage_loading)], debug=True)

def main():
  run_wsgi_app(app)

if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```